# SPF redirect modifier

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, spf

> The SPF record for domain replace the current record. The
>   macro-expanded domain is also substituted for the current-domain in
>   those look-ups.
>
> Examples:
>
> In the following example, the client IP is 1.2.3.4 and the
>   current-domain is example.com.
>
> "v=spf1 redirect=example.com"
>
> If example.com has no SPF record, that is an error; the result is
>   unknown. Suppose example.com's SPF record was "v=spf1 a -all". Look up
>   the A record for example.com. If it matches 1.2.3.4, return Pass. If
>   there is no match, the exec fails to match, and the -all value is
>   used.

The *domain* and *current-domain* meaning is not very clear here.

What happens, if example1.com spf was queried,

```
example1.com IN MX 0 mx.example1.com.    
example1.com IN TXT "v=spf1 redirect=example2.com"
mx.example1.com IN A 1.1.1.1

example2.com IN MX 0 mx.example2.com.
example2.com IN TXT "v=spf1 mx -all"
mx.example2.com IN A 2.2.2.2
```

Should the spf result be 1.1.1.1 OR 2.2.2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `redirect` to a domain, the redirected domain becomes the target for all subsequent DNS lookups, such as those performed by `mx`.

See [RFC 7208 § 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-6.1):

> The <domain-spec> portion of the redirect section is expanded as per the macro rules in Section 7.  Then check_host() is evaluated with the resulting string as the <domain>. The <ip> and <sender> arguments remain the same as in the current evaluation of check_host().

Comment: So the answer is 2.2.2.2.